# Dereferencing pointer to void

Tags: c, hashmap

I am working on an implementation of a hashmap in C, and the function for `CMapPut` is defined as follows:

```
void CMapPut(CMap *cm, const char *key, const void *elemAddr)
```

My question is how do I retrieve the actual value of the element passed into the map? That is, when the client passes in the variables, he passes in the address of the value. In this case it appears to be a `void *` though, and of course you can't dereference a `void *`. Any tips?

Comment: cast to your datatype pointer.

Comment: You do have to know yourself what the datatype is, of course.  There are languages that have facilities to keep track of the datatype, but C isn't one of them.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to cast the pointer to the type you need:

```
typedef struct {
    ...
} CMyType;

...

CMyType myinstance;
CMapPut(cm, "key", &myinstance);
```

I guess you'll store the pointer as `const void*`. I guess you have a function like `CMapGet`, you use to retrieve your mapped objects like this:

```
void *CMapGet(CMap *cm, const char *key);

...

CMyType* myinstance_ptr = CMapGet(cm, key);
```

Comment: To expand on this a bit, in your `CMapPut` function, you'd do this: `const ActualValueType value = *((ActualValueType*)elemAddr);`

Answer (score 0):

Cast your `void *` to your appropiate type, as mentioned by others. Second, you don't have to `const` your attribute `elemAddr`. It's no use, since you probably want to return a non-const pointer anyway.